Does zref replace hyperref?
I quite recently stumbled over zref. According to its documentation and the one of zref-clever, the one benefit is that with these packages we don't need to hack LaTeX's referencing system anymore (like hyperref seems to do).
Are there actually attempts to replace the hyperref package (or attempts to split it into multiple packages so that I can avoid the \label redefinition)?
From what I have read, zref(-clever) does far less than hyperref (sounds a bit unfair, maybe does different things is better wording). If so and this is no attempt to replace hyperref, then (at the current state) I'd still need to load hyperref if I want e.g. hyperlinks so I still "suffer" from the redefinition of \label right?
Yes this is more a high-level question rather than a technical one. I hope my question became clear (Not sure though). I'm basically thinking of how much of a benefit zref(-clever) brings to me as a user because in the current state replacing/avoiding hyperref is kinda out of scope I think (is it?)

the question in the title is a clear no, but zref is largely replaced by the new ltproperties code in the latex format and hyperref will over time be merged into the format as well. hyperref no longer redefines \label as the standard format now always uses \label with 5 fields rather than two, so that it is compatible with hyperref use.

So the general direction for latex is not to make labels as generic as zref does but to adapt to the needs that were derived from the (years of) experience with hyperref (at least by default). So should zref be more considered a "bridging technology"? And to a user the (of course maybe biased) recomendation would be to mostly stick with hyperref/cleverref (and wait for latex to further evolve)?

there really isn't so much overlap, hyperref is mostly about making hyperlinks which isn't that related to zref, zref is about extending cross references with labeled properties that can be set in one place and retrieved elsewhere and that model (with a slightly different implementation) is largely copied by ltproperties.

Concurring with @DavidCarlisle, indeed hyperref and zref/zref-clever have different purposes. And the latter uses (and needs) hyperref for hyperlinking. Not sure I agree with "replaced" though. ;-)

@gusbrs Maybe the claim is ... er ... aspirational ...? (This is how I interpret egreg on etoolbox, for example.)
